# Zend select box Default Value Select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

Here is my code. I need AM to be selected by default. Hence i have set AM in value. but not working.I am using zend2.

```
      $format = array('AM'=>'AM','PM'=>'PM');
      $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
        'name' => 'start_format',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'start_format',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'options' => $format,
            'value'=>'AM'
        ),
         'options' => array(
          'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
          ),

    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with `options\value_options` instead of `attributes\options` :

```
$format = array('AM'=>'AM','PM'=>'PM');
  $this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'name' => 'start_format',
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'start_format',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'value'=>'AM'
    ),
     'options' => array(
      'value_options => $format,
      'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
      ),
));
```